# What really happens when the a program is paused by Edit>Mark from the command line?

Tags: windows, multithreading, jvm, cmd

When running programs from the command line in Windows, if Mark mode is entered then the program output pauses, giving you plenty of time to copy whatever you need and then continue program execution.

I always assumed that this just paused the output stream, and the program continued behind regardless. However, I have found that it also seems to 'pause' the program as well (or at the very least prevent it communicating through sockets).

My question is: what does this 'pausing' actually entail? Which threads are suspended? Are child processes suspended (I'm guessing not)? If running Java code, for example, is the whole JVM suspended, or just the main thread? How does Windows actually handle this?

I apologise if this may be a little open-ended as a question, but with QuickEdit mode switched on I'd like to know what risk there is with critical programs!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the threads which are communicating through sockets aren't *also* trying to write to the console?

Comment: All logging is processed with NLog, and there isn't any direct console access in the program in question. Assuming Nlog runs on a separate thread then this should affect it.

Comment: It sounds like that's an assumption you should verify. I would try writing a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Selecting text in the console window will block the Standard Output pipe. This means that when a thread attempts to write to standard out, it will also block until all the data in the pipe is read and everything starts moving again.

This does *not* block any other threads or child processes.

You can use [GetConsoleSelectionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if a user has selected text, and potentially warn them or take other actions.